# Embedded JavaScript doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Well, I'm working on Wordpress Theme and I've a very strange behavior.

When I put my jQuery script in script tag (anywhere on the site) it works like charm.

But when I try to link to a file with the same script, like:

`<script src="address" type="text/javascript"></script>` - it doesn't.

What's wrong? The link is VALID. The script was tested in the beginning but also at the end of a site (so that's no "on load" problem).

How to troubleshoot problems like that? Is there a way to debug JavaScript in Opera?

Can't provide a link.

Thanks

Comment: What do you put for `address`?

Comment: You need to show more code. Where are you doing this? What behaviour are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you all were wrong, the answer was:

$(something) works only inline and when embedded - Wordpress accepts only jQuery instead of the dollar sign, so everything works fine after changing all "$" to "jQuery" :)

Anyways thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

a javascript file should ends with `.js`, probably path and especially file name is wrong

take a look at firebug (or opera console) if this get returns a 404 error

Answer (score 1):

Like @Fabrizio Calderan said, maybe the script URL is wrong? Or maybe because of lack of `js` extension server doesn't send proper mime type and browser has a problem with interpreting the file.
Also if it's wordpress, you probably rewrite post's URLs somehow - if the script is in your domain's root directory you should put `/` before filename, if it's in a template directory try what @Nick Pyett proposed.

Yes, you can debug JavaScript in Opera - check out [Opera Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the wp_enqueue_script() function. More here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script is a .js file, is in your template folder and the line is being included between the html head tags...

```
<script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url')?>/address.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Check the trailing slash after the php because i can't remember if the function includes one off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to View - Developer Tools  and check Opera Dragonfly, you will see Dragonfly open in the bottom of the browser, which appears to have similar capabilities to Firebug for Firefox (DOM browser, Network monitor, Script debugger, etc). This may help you get to the root of your problem.